# Inserting file content to mysql table

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to insert the contant of a .txt file into a mysql table. The command is this, but I'm having problems with the LOAD_FILE:
(already tried with absolut and relative path for the file)

```
FILE="LOAD_FILE('/home/vector5/scripts/log_Backup_HG3DiesSetmana.txt')"

mysql --host=localhost --user=MYUSER --password=MYPASSWORD vector5_apLogis2 << EOF

insert into tableNameBackups(data,tipus,titol,text) 
values('2015-06-02 00:47:17','111','asdadad',$FILE);

EOF
```

And this is the error I have, looks like is not reading the file. I've tried almost everything with no luck:

```
ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 1: Column 'text' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$taulaAUsar` is undefined. Check if it contains the table name.

**UPDATE**

$file is null make sure that the file exists. Think you have to add the complete path to it.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, when setting a correct value for the table, the error is this one:

ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 1: Column 'text' cannot be null

Comment: With path "~/scripts/log_Backup_HG3DiesSetmana.txt" I have the same error.